# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]: Ionic Emulate

Tags: android, android-emulator, ionic-framework

I want to develop an android application using Ionic framework.
I can able to view the output in browser.

But after 
ionic platform add android

i have build the project using (used Android 19 version)
ionic build android --> which created my android-debug.apk file.

I want to emulate my application. 
ionic run android

Getting Below Error:
Failed to launch app on emulator: Failed to install apk to emulator:    pkg: /da
ta/local/tmp/android-debug.apk

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]

I have tried to track the log:
adb logcat *:E

Getting Below log.

```
E/NetdConnector(  367): NDC Command {51 bandwidth removeiquota eth0} took too lo
ng (559ms)
E/NetdConnector(  367): NDC Command {53 bandwidth setiquota eth0 922337203685477
5807} took too long (1037ms)
E/NetdConnector(  367): NDC Command {55 bandwidth setiquota eth0 922337203685477
5807} took too long (1230ms)
E/memtrack(  890): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
E/android.os.Debug(  890): failed to load memtrack module: -2
E/installd(   61): dexopt in='/data/app/com.ionicframework.test638461-1.apk' out
='/data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.ionicframework.test638461-1.apk@classes.dex' r
es=65280
```

Some of the other solution like 
1) wipe user data in  adb
2) Kill adb and start again
3) Emulate in geny motion.
4) remove ionic and install again
5) remove and add platform again.
None of the above worked for me.

Another problem i dont know anything about java.

Can anyone pls help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Can anyone guide me for above issue

Answer (score 0):

Ionic can't do `ionic run android` with emulator, it can only work with real device or genymotion.

Instead they provide other option, you can try this: `ionic emulate android` or `ionic emulate android -l` to enable the powerful livereload feature.

P/S: Genymotion couldn't work with `ionic run emulate` also.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: 1) ionic emulate android -l : Listed out the virtual devices. After selection of virtual device. 
Again building the apk and still facing the same error.

2) ionic run emulate : Whether command is correct???
After running above getting Error:"Unknown platforms: emulate"

Comment: Can u guide me for above issue

Comment: @Vigneshsrinivasan Sorry about that, It's my mistake, the correct command is `ionic emulate android`

Comment: I have tried with ionic emulate android its not working getting same error. Any other solution.

Comment: I want to test my app in the emulator.